# Exporting org to ascii without line breaks

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

In org-mode (8.2.5) is there any way to export to ascii without line breaks being inserted at the end of every line in the .txt file?

A good canditate would have been:

```
(setq org-ascii-text-width nil)
```

But nil isn't accepted as an argument for `org-ascii-text-width`.

An un-elegant work-around is:

```
(setq org-ascii-text-width 1000)
```

Assuming that none of my paragraphs are more that 1000 characters long.

If I:

```
(setq org-ascii-text-width 10000)
```

I get the error:

```
Stack overflow in regexp matcher
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out the code in my answer below? If there's anything you are unclear about, let me know. I'd be happy to add more information about the solution I proposed.

Comment: Didn't get a chance yet. Will do when I get back to my computer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat embarrassing:

Removing the `org-ascii-text-width`-variable all together does what I need: no breaks are added when I export to ascii.

I started fiddling with `org-ascii-text-width` when I noticed line breaks being added in exported text and I wrongly assumed it was due to an update to org 8.2.5.

The cause of this was something else. I must have inadvertently set `fill-column` or something similar.

Comment: `(setq org-ascii-text-width most-positive-fixnum)` worked for me (no stackoverflow as described in the question question.)

Comment: Removing org-ascii-text-width results in an error upon export `Symbol's value as variable is void`. Setting it to most-positive-fixnum causes Emacs to hard crash when exporting a buffer.

Comment: Emacs 26.3b1/macos: set `org-ascii-text-width` to `most-positive-fixnum` result in emacs eats up all memory during export and hangs. Removing `org-ascii-text-width `with `makeunbound` results in error during export. So I've stayed with value 1000

Answer (score 2):

The [`misc-commands`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el) package defines a function called `goto-longest-line`. Using this function, we can define a function that sets `org-ascii-text-width` to the length of the longest line in the current buffer:

```
(defun org-set-ascii-text-width ()
  (save-excursion (setq org-ascii-text-width
                        (cadr (goto-longest-line (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

To make sure `org-ascii-text-width` gets updated every time you save an `org-mode` buffer, add it to `before-save-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
          (lambda () (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
                         (org-set-ascii-text-width))))
```

---

`misc-commands` is available in [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) and can be `package-install`ed (after [adding MELPA to the list of package archives](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started) for the Emacs Package Manager).

If you don't want to install the package I guess you could also head over [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el), grab the `goto-longest-line` function and add it to your `.emacs` (along with a comment that mentions the original author, of course).

Comment: + 1 one for a good solution but didn't accept. The solution of removing the `org-ascii-text-width`. Should have done a better job of eliminating sources of error before posting. Sorry!

Comment: Misc-commands is not present in Melpa, at least as far as I can tell: https://melpa.org/#/?q=misc%20commands